Insert array of composite types into column of type array of composite type
let's say I have a self-declared composite type 'address' and I get f.e. a variable 'customers', where an array of addresses is just stored as plain object. How would I insert this into a table with a column of type 'address[]' into a single row?
(I tried it with json_populate_recordset(null::address, $1) and JSON.stringify(customers), but that didn't work.)

You're on the right track with the json_populate_recordset() idea. You can use it to unpack the json array as a plain set of address, then pack it back up into an address[] array  using array_agg():
select array_agg(an_address) as array_of_addresses
from json_populate_recordset(null::address,$3) as setofaddresses(an_address);

Note that if you pass an empty array as $3 to the query above, it'll have a null as the array_of_addresses. ARRAY() constructor syntax lets you plug a subselect into it, shortening that to:
select array(select json_populate_recordset(null::address,'[]') );

Which gets you an empty array in cases where $3 is an empty array, instead of the previous null.
Here's an example:
create type address as (
    street_name text
  , street_no int
  , zip_code text
  , city text
  , state text);
create table subscribers (
    id bigint generated by default as identity primary key
  , first_name text
  , last_name text
  , addresses address[]);

prepare insert_into_subscribers(text, text, json) as
insert into subscribers(first_name, last_name, addresses)
values($1, $2, array(select json_populate_recordset(null::address,$3)) );

execute insert_into_subscribers( 'John'
                                ,'Doe'
                                ,'[ { "street_name": "Sesame Street"
                                     ,"street_no":3
                                     ,"zip_code":"432ABC234"
                                     ,"city":"New York"
                                     ,"state":"NY"}
                                   ,{ "street_name": "Lincoln Boulevard"
                                     ,"street_no":4
                                     ,"zip_code":"432ABC235"
                                     ,"city":"Albuquerque"
                                     ,"state":"NM"}]');
select*from subscribers;




id
first_name
last_name
addresses




1
John
Doe
{"("Sesame Street",3,432ABC234,"New York",NY)","("Lincoln Boulevard",4,432ABC235,Albuquerque,NM)"}



select id, first_name, last_name, addr.* 
from subscribers 
cross join lateral unnest(addresses)with ordinality as addr;




id
first_name
last_name
street_name
street_no
zip_code
city
state
ordinality




1
John
Doe
Sesame Street
3
432ABC234
New York
NY
1


1
John
Doe
Lincoln Boulevard
4
432ABC235
Albuquerque
NM
2




Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using this syntax like you:
insert into subscribers(first_name, last_name, addresses)
values($1, $2, array[json_populate_recordset(null::address,$3)] );
(I have to put JSON.stringify around the variable I pass to $3, otherwise it complains about "invalid input syntax for type json").
When I execute it, it only works if the array has exactly length one. For an empty array, it doesn't create a row and for multiple addresses I get unique key violations. I suppose it inserts one row in the table for each of the addresses now?

The initial array[] idea resulted in an empty set (thus no insert), but you can instead get a null or an empty array in those cases using the other two examples I just added. As to the unique key violations, you'd have to show your table structure, PK/unique constraints and what you did exactly. The example I'm showing above could only get that error if I tried to override the id that's in my case auto-generated.

select array[json_populate_recordset(null::address,$3)] is wrong, that produces multiple (zero, one, more…) rows with single-element arrays. Not what you want. (I'm quite surprised calling set-returning functions works inside values syntax at all)

I can tell you that there are two other columns in the table, which in combination of values have to be unique. That's why I suspected that some flattening happens now and it creates one row per address in our case.

@Bergi Fixed, thanks. You made me triple-check the demo and I realised I overlooked that both final selects showed multiple entries regardless of whether I exploded the array or not, meaning it kept inserting single-element arrays, which also explains OP's case. I threw that out now, leaving just the array_agg() and the array() subselect constructor syntax.

With this fix it works now. Thanks!
